# Tint UIButton when tapped?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

Is there a way to set a tint color on a UIButton using an image, so while a finger is on the button the tint overlays the image? It would be nice to have such a highlight effect while the button is tapped, instead of doubling the number of button images.

Comment: I think the general principle on iOS is to prefer to use double the images, so all the work is done on the desktop. You are optimizing against the grain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are literally just trying to reduce the amount of assets in your project you could potentially make a subclass of `UIButton` and override `setImage:forState:`

```
- (void)setImage:(UIImage *)image forState:(UIControlState)state;
{
  [super setImage:image forState:state];

  UIImage *processImage = // Process the image to add tint
  [self setHighlightImage:processedImage forState:state];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use setHighlightImage:forState or setImage:forState: using the state UIControlStateHighlighted